# Compilable custom environment when in the body text becomes uncompilable when defined as a new environment

Tags: tables, color, environments, colortbl

I attempted to make a table which has gray backgound cells except for the first column and the first row colored blue. The following code successfully generates the desired output (although I do not know this over-painting method is a good way to make what I want, and the command `\arrayrulecolor{tabuline}` becomes somehow valid globally outside the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tabularbg}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{tabuline}{named}{white} % whiten the line color
\colorlet{tabularul}{blue!30}
\begin{document}
    \begingroup
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
        \arrayrulecolor{tabuline}
        \colorbox{tabularbg}%
        {%
        \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{tabularul}}r|r|r|r}
            \rowcolor{tabularul}
            $\times$ & negative & zero & positive \\
            \hline
            negative & $+$ & $0$ & $-$ \\
            \hline
            zero & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
            \hline
            positive & $-$ & $0$ & $+$
        \end{tabular}%
        }
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: table I first get]

I think of making this table a new environment, say `mytabular` environment, and Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tabularbg}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{tabuline}{named}{white} % whiten the line color
\colorlet{tabularul}{blue!30}
\newenvironment{mytabular}[3]{%
    \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \colorbox{#3}{%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{#2}}#1}
        \rowcolor{#2}
}{%
    \end{tabular}%
    }\endgroup
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{mytabular}{rrrr}{tabularul}{tabularbg}
        $\times$ & negative & zero & positive \\
        \hline
        negative & $+$ & $0$ & $-$ \\
        \hline
        zero & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
        \hline
        positive & $-$ & $0$ & $+$
    \end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

Then, I get a error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`. If I put a blank line avobe `\begin{document}`, this time the error is:

```
! Misplaced \crcr.
\endarray ->\crcr
                  \egroup \egroup \gdef \@preamble {}\CT@end
l.17 ...n{mytabular}{rrrr}{tabularul}{tabularbg}
```

It seems to me that the definition of `mytabular` environment does not include any mistakes because both errors occurs after that. How should I fix the code?

Comment: You can't break the argument of `\colorbox{}` like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way for this is to use `lrbox`; the only quirk is to carry the third argument to the “end part”, which is easy with `\colorlet`.

The problem is that you can't open `\colorbox{<color>}{` in the “begin part” and close it in the “end part”. So, with `lrbox` we store the tabular in a storage bin and use it later as argument to `\colorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{tabularbg}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{tabuline}{named}{white} % whiten the line color
\colorlet{tabularul}{blue!30}

\newsavebox{\mytabularbox}
\newenvironment{mytabular}[3]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \arrayrulecolor{tabuline}%
  \colorlet{mytabularcolor}{#3}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mytabularbox}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{#2}}#1}
  \rowcolor{#2}
}{%
  \end{tabular}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \colorbox{mytabularcolor}{\usebox{\mytabularbox}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabular}{r|r|r|r}{tabularul}{tabularbg}
$\times$ & negative & zero & positive \\
\hline
negative & $+$ & $0$ & $-$ \\
\hline
zero & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
\hline
positive & $-$ & $0$ & $+$
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I have never heard of `lrbox` before, but today I learned this useful technique for making environment. Thank you.

Comment: One question occurred to me. I thought, in my first code, `\columncolor`  and `\rowcolor` changed the gray cells into blue because they were written after `\colorbox`. However, in your code, the last execution related to color is `\colorbox`, but the output keeps the desired color pattern. Is there an order of priority in these coloring commands and others such as `\rowcolors` and `\cellcolor`?

Comment: @Merzong `\cellcolor` just colors the background, which is overprinted by the box contents. It's no different from your compiling example.

Comment: What do you mean by "the box contents"?

Comment: @Merzong The argument to `\colorbox`

Comment: I was confused because I misread your comment as `\cellcolor` colors the background and _then_ it is overprinted by the _first_ argument (i.e. color) to `\colorbox`. But now I understand the meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`environ`](http://www.ctan.org/pck/environ) package instead to capture the body of the environment so as to avoid problems with the `\colorbox` opening in the begin part and closing in the end part of a standard `\newenvironment`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}

\definecolor{tabularbg}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{tabuline}{named}{white} % whiten the line color
\colorlet{tabularul}{blue!30}

\NewEnviron{mytabular}[3]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \colorbox{#3}{%
    \arrayrulecolor{tabuline}%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{#2}}#1}
        \rowcolor{#2}\BODY
    \end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabular}{r|rrr}{tabularul}{tabularbg}
        $\times$ & negative & zero & positive \\
        \hline
        negative & $+$ & $0$ & $-$ \\
        \hline
        zero & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
        \hline
        positive & $-$ & $0$ & $+$
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Environments form a group so no need for explicit use of `\begingroup`, `\endgroup`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I understand why my code is incorrect and yours works fine.  By the way, is there any way to define macros like this in the definition of which we have to split the braces of a certain macro without the `environ` package?

Comment: @Merzong Yes. I was about to provide the answer without `environ`, but egreg already did.